# Image texture not showing on object

Tags: node-editor, image

I set up the diffuse material, add a image texture node, select the image and yet everything remains beige. Any ideas? The tutorial I was following along it worked just fine when he did it... but he was using v2.6x

[image]

Comment: If you do have UVMaps make sure the one you are using is first, not the one you used for the painting. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably didn't add a uvmap. A UV map is what maps the 3d coordinates of the object to the 2d coordinates of the Image being used as a texture.

[image]

Notice *properties -> Data -> UV Maps* has no entries.

The simplest way to see a texture there is to press the + symbol to the right. Your viewport rendering will show a texture on the Cube.

See blender's manual page about [uv_mapping](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/uv_image/uv_mapping.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, try unwrapping it as a cube in editmode by selecting the whole cube and then click on mesh, then uv unwrap and then cube projection. maybe it works then.